# ECONNREFUSED error in docker-compose with NodeJS and postgresql in google cloud

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, econnrefused

I have created my react app with Node.js and postgresql and I deployed in google cloud. I created a docker image of postgres and nodejs and I uploaded images to docker hub. From gcloud I accessing Those images.

This is my docker-compose-production.yml file.

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  postgres:
    image : mycompany/myapp:pglatest
    restart : always
    volumes:
      - ./backdata/databackups:/var/lib/postgresql/backdata
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

  backend:
    image: mycompany/myapp:nodelatest7
    command: npm run start
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URL: postgresql://postgres:root@postgres:5432/db_mydb 
      DEBUG: hms-backend:*
```

when I run command

`sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml up --build -d`

2 images are created.

after that I have run tail command

`sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml logs -t backend`

I'm getting error as

> backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.926001351Z REST API listening on port 5000
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937246598Z error { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.80.2:5432
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937268668Z     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937280934Z   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937283960Z   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937286817Z   syscall: 'connect',
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937289488Z   address: '192.168.80.2',
>   
>   backend_1   | 2018-09-15T09:12:18.937292260Z   port: 5432 }

How to solve this problem

Comment: You should check in postgresql.conf if postgres is configured to listen on all interfaces (`*`) instead of `localhost` which is the default

Comment: Thank You for reply. I tried this but it didn't not solve my problem

Comment: Are your sure that your `mycompany/myapp:pglatest` has exposed 5432 port? It suppose to have `EXPOSE 5432` in the Dockerfile for that image.

Answer (score 0):

For me your postgres url is wrong : postgresql://postgres:root@postgres:5432/db_mydb

It should be postgresql://postgres:root@postgres:**5433**/db_mydb since the postgres "exposed" port in 5433

Hum, by i think you should  add "container_name" in the docker-compose

```
services:
  postgres:
     container_name: my_postgres
```

and use this name for the "adress" of your postgres

**postgresql://my_postgres:root@postgres:5433/db_mydb**

Comment: Thank you for reply.This didn't solve my problem I am getting same error

Comment: Just in case, the new configuration was used by docker ? so you got on your log  "port 5433" ?

Comment: I edited the answer, have you tried with container_name ?

Comment: I have changed that but I am facing same problem.thank you for your reply.